# Не работает nvidia-docker на debian

Tags: debian, docker, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Установил docker, драйвер Nvidia и nvidia-container-toolkit.

Выполняю команду:

````bsh
nvidia-docker run -p 7777:8888 -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu jupyter notebook --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=''```
````

И получаю следующую ошибку

```
bash: nvidia-docker: command not found
```

Кто-то знает в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Ну, скорее всего утилита nvidia-docker  не записана в системные переменные. Вам для начала нужно понять, куда вы ее установили(может быть /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin  и еще в паре мест. После чего попробуйте запустить через абсолютный или относительный путь(например, usr/bin/nvidia-docker run -p 7777:8888 -it...

Если все ок, тогда можно будет добавить команду в перменные.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: делаю find / -name 'nvidia-docker' вывод пуст

Comment: а так? `sudo systemctl start nvidia-docker`? После чего `nvidia-docker run...`

Comment: sudo systemctl start nvidia-docker
Failed to start nvidia-docker.service: Unit nvidia-docker.service not found.